# Function keys in Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, function-keys

I have just installed Lubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander but my function keys for media (such as play pause etc.) are not working. I can change brightness and volume with the function keys and I am certainly sure that my function keys were working with Ubuntu 13.04. I am currently using HP-mini. Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: see this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

**This helped me; not a fix for use across programs (I might dive into that at a later time) but worked for the main program I use the media keys with: Clementine.
I got this off another forum http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=30483 
*Be sure to make a backup beforehand, and once you have edited and saved the file, run `openbox --reconfigure` so openbox will read the new file. Thank you "Member"!***

Okay,
guys from IRC helped me with this problem, so I'll post solution:

I edited rc.xml from Openbox. I read clementine's manual to see how can I control it from CLI.
After reading it, I came up with these lines:

```
<!-- Keybindings for Media Keys -->
<keybind key="XF86AudioMute">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>amixer set Master toggle</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>clementine --volume-down</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>clementine --volume-up</command>
  </action>
</keybind>

 <keybind key="XF86AudioPlay">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>clementine -t</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioPrev">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>clementine --previous</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioNext">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>clementine --next</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

And it works smile Hope it will help someone